# Header view not showing at Section 0

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, sections

I add custom `tableView` header. My section count is 2 and the header is not displaying at section 0. But showing properly at section 1.

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrRouteDetials.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {
            headerRadioBtn.tag = section
            headerRadioBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(RdAction(_sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)

            return viewTblHeader
        }else{
            headerRadioBtn.tag = section
            headerRadioBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(RdAction(_sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)

            return viewTblHeader
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrOfSectionRowValue[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BranchUnloadingcell", for: indexPath) as! BranchUnloadingcell
        cell.lblSerialNo.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        cell.val = arrOfSectionRowValue[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 74
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the same header, `viewTblHeader`, for both section 0 and 1? They should be unique instances. Also, there should be no need to call `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in `willDisplay`.

Comment: I want same header in every Section. viewWillLayoutSubviews is used to set table height constant.

Comment: That's not going to work. They need to be different instances. That is likely your problem.